# How to assign formatted column value in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am executing query `select avg, min, max from table`

Now, I am having datatable.

Query returning decimal and integer values.
For Decimal, I have to format by comma with precision and for integer just by comma and show datatable.

Now, I am iterating each row of the column and formatting as:

`String.Format("{0:#,#,0.00}", resultDataTable.Rows[0][0])`

It is giving me desired result "1,555,222.20"

now, I have to assign it to resultDataTable.Rows[0][0] so that it should be same on UI

Its not assigning

Comment: How are you displaying this data? Typically one uses a UI control to display a DataTable's data, and that UI control has formatting options built into it so that you don't format data at the DataTable level...

Comment: Agreeing with @HereticMonkey here. Formatting is generally for your UI to perform. Let the data be whatever it is underneath. Just change it for the humans at the layer in which they interact with it. Let the computer keep it in the format it likes. They everyone is happy.

Comment: Ok, but in case I want to change datatable result, so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**If you can change the type of the column**

Considering what you have asked, it seems that you have two different data tables. I think you can completely discriminate between what you have behind the scene and what you are going to depict in the user interface. Therefore, one likely solution is to keep the formatted data in a string column. So, by changing the type of the data column you can simply achieve what you are looking for.

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Using this strategy, you do not need to format the received decimal item.

**If you are restricted to use a concrete data table**

Even if you are restricted to use a concrete data table, you shouldn't have any problem. 
The only thing you need to do is to format the received data inside the user interface.

I hope this answer is useful.

Comment: Without changing the type, is it possible to assign the value ?

Comment: What is the technology of the user interface? Is it a web application or what? As it was cited before you can simply format your received data. If I know what technology you are exactly using, I may be able to tell you how to handle your data inside the user interface.

Comment: It is a web application with datatable on UI